# How deep I can go with asking inner field

Tags: python

I am learning Python and I can't understand 2 things.
I have this code.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field

t = Test("field")
t.field_2 = t
print(t.field_2.field_2.field_2.field_2.field)
```

In the last line I can't understand how deep can I go.
As I understand as memory is not infinitive - I can't go deerep always.

Comment: You are not going "deeper" but in circles.

Comment: Python references are *not copies*. `t.field_2 = t` creates a reference to `t`, so `t.field_2 is t` is true, which is why `t.field_2.field_2` is still *the same object*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can. To demonstrate this:

```
while t != None:
    t = t.field_2
    print(t.field)
```

This will run forever.

You reuse the same object, so that the memory doesn't grow. `field_2` just stores pointer to the object (an address in the memory) rather than the object itself, and that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's like a circle. You can make infinitely many loops while still staying in a finite space.